Symfony - how to refresh one form based on changes in the other one?
I've got two forms on the web page, sitting next to each other.
Both are created in live components.
I need to refresh 2nd form, based on changes in the 1st one.
What is the best approach to achieve this?

It would be good to know what you mean with 'refresh'. (For example) if I enter 'ice cream' in form A, should that then generate a list of available toppings in form B? Or should it simply mirror values or should it refresh? Please provide your current live component PHP and twig as well. This would definitely help.

Agreed, my question was very broad and have managed to solve this issue
by using live components, LiveAction, LiveListener and emit() method.
